# Jquery File Upload Plugin not working in partial view MVC4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload

I have downloaded jQuery Fiel upload plugin from NuGet pakages in VS2013. By default there is a sample code generated with controller and views , This code and plugin works fine in the sample and in other views but when I try using the same code in `Partial View` the plugin doesn't work. I have very little knowledge in jQuery and AJAX. Need help to get it working with partial views.

Comment: Have you included a reference to the script file inside the view that contains the partial view?

Comment: did you get  it working.having same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize  fileupload  in Partial View again. Its help to me.
$(elem).fileupload({ ....});

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that you might be missing a reference to the plugin script within your page.

Somewhere on your parent view or partial view you should include a reference as such:

```
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
```

Of course the path and file name should be the ones you have in your project.

Hope this helps.

For further reading on how to include scripts in HTML you can check:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp

Comment: I have added the scripts. And its not working. If I just copy paste the same code in a main view I get it working fine but why not in partial view?. :(

Comment: @Reddy could you post both view codes? i.e. the one that works fine and the one that has the partial view that doesn't work?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. The only thing I feel is there is some changes needed to be made in the plugin to be used in partial view. I am looking for that.

Comment: How are you rendering your Partial View? Are you doing it through AJAX? If so, you will need to rebind the plugin to your upload button/link within the `success` callback in order for it to work again. If not, it will be interpreted as a simple button or link.

Comment: I am using MVC Razor syntax `@Html.RenderPartial("PartialViewName")` to call my pratial view. Actually the View name is dynamically created by HtmlHelper classes. But at the end of the day its all the same.

Comment: I still think it could be that the button/link is not getting bound to the plugin because it's loaded in a partial view. You could try adding a `<script type="text/javascript">` section to your partial view and then bind the plugin inside the `$(document).ready` function. But all this must be within your partial view code not the parent view that renders it.

Comment: It doesn't work in partial view. I tried adding the script in partial view as you have mentioned but no use.

Comment: This is mind boggling. I am going to try and create a demo project and see what I find. I truly want to get to the bottom of this. Can you tell me the exact NuGet package name or the link so I can download it?

Comment: :) go to Manage Nuget Pakages, There find for a `Jquery File Upload Plugin` (this is the exact name). By default you will have a controller a view associated with it and bundle scripts. You can just go to the view and find the plugin working fine. The plugin is exactly as this one http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/